# Yii2 active record: using a relation with limit returns nothing

Tags: activerecord, yii2

In my project I am trying to return related data by calling the relation by uisng `with()` , the problem is when I set the `limit()`in the relation not data returned .

my code so far : 
relation

```
public function getRequestNoteLess(){
    return $this->hasMany(RequestNote::className(), ['request_id'=>'id'])
                ->orderBy(['is_admin'=>SORT_DESC,'id'=>SORT_DESC])
                ->limit(3);
}
```

query

```
$out =  Request::find()->select(['id','IF('.$t.' = 0, 0, 1) as userType','agent','id', 'source','reference',
        'type','bedrooms','agent', 'size','budget',
        'interested', 'full_name','phone','email',
        'note','for','furnished', 'user_id','updated_by',
        'inserted_at','updated_at', 'price','showed','offered',
        'status','phone2','phone3', 'area','priority' ,'feed_back'])->where($where)->with('sources')->with('exchange')->with(['agen'=>function($q){$q->select(['username','id']);}])->with(['requestNoteLess'=>function($q){$q->select('*')->limit(3)->all();}])->orderBy(['id'=>SORT_DESC])->groupBy(['id'])->limit(300)->asArray()->all();

    return json_encode($out);
```

Comment: And when you remove the limit all works fine (just without the limitation)?

Comment: yes this what happened @robsch

Comment: Are you load your data by `ActiveDataProvider` and use it in `GridView`?
If your answer is yes, you should config `pageSize` in class `ActiveDataProvider`

Comment: no I am returning data as json encode @ThanhPV

Comment: Please add your code for `json_encode()`

Comment: @ThanhPV question updated

Comment: Wow, thank you for reverting my formatting efforts.

Comment: I searched and found that now can't use `limit` in relations. So I don't have answer for your question.
I keep finding answer for it.
Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when  you use complex sql and eventully you need feature not covered by some framework function you can use  `findBySql`  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activerecord.html#findBySql()-detail

```
 $sql = 'Select ........';
 $model = YourModel::findBySql($sql)->all();
```

or queryAll if the query is not strictly related to a model

```
 $model = $connection->createCommand('SELECT * FROM Your_table');
 $yourModel = $model->queryAll();
```

take a look at this for some suggestion  http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/select-query-sql-queries/